# Prove that $f_n(x) = \cos^{n} x$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0, \pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Prove that $f_n(x) = \cos^{n} x$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0, \pi]$

Intuitively I can see that if $x=0$ or $x = \pi$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n (x) = 1$ but if $x \in (0,\pi)$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)  = 0$.

I tried to explain that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\{ \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\} = 0$ but $f_n(0) = 1$ so the limit does not exist which would imply that there is also no possible uniform convergence.

What is the right approach?

Comment: First determine what's the pointwise limit of $f_n(x)$. Does it exist for $x=\pi$, i.e. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \cos^n \pi =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\cos \pi)^n=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (-1)^n$?

Comment: Note that $\cos^{2n}(\sqrt{1/n})\to e^{-1}$.

Comment: The question was originally posed to me as $cos^{2n} x$.  In the question here I wrote it as $cos^n x$.  Your argument for $cos(\pi)^n = (-1)^n$ is clear.  I will leave the question unchanged to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions has a continuous limit.

Notice that the limit of
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n (x) = 
\begin{cases} 1 \\
0\\
-1 \end{cases}$$
So by the contrapositive, because the limit is not continuous, the sequence is not uniformly convergent.